# Updating a value when v-model changes

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have a text input with `v-model` binding it's value to `data`. I would also like to be able to call my `parse()` function when this `v-model` value changes in order to update an array that is also on `data`.

```
<div id="app">
    <input
        id="user-input"
        type="text"
        v-model="userInput">

   <ul id="parsed-list">
      <li v-for="item in parsedInput">
          {{ item }}
      </li>
    </ul>
</div>

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    userInput: '',
    parsedInput: []
  }
})

let parse = input => {
    return input.split(',')
}
```

How should I go about updating `data.parsedInput` with the `parse()` function using the v-model change? What is the proper Vue way of doing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A proper Vue way of a data property that depends on another is with a [computed property](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/computed.html#Computed-Properties), that way `parsedInput` is automatically updated whenever `userInput` changes:

```js
let parse = input => {
  return input.split(',')
}

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    userInput: '',
  },
  computed: {
    parsedInput() {
        return parse(this.userInput)
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.2.1/vue.js"></script>
<body>
  <div id="app">
    <input id="user-input" type="text" v-model="userInput">

    <ul id="parsed-list">
      <li v-for="item in parsedInput">
        {{ item }}
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</body>
```

As a sidenote: declare the `parse` function before using it, to prevent `is not defined` errors.